How to slowly print line of dashes in terminal?
I'm new to python and am trying out some basic while loops in the terminal.
Basically I'm trying to print 80 dashes to the terminal using python with a time delay of 0.2s between each dash so that it has the effect of loading the line of dashes. However, all the program does is wait 16s (80 x 0.2) and then print the line all at once, instead of waiting between dashes.
The set-up I've used is a while loop, detailed below:
import time
i = 0
while i < 80:
    print("-", end="")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    i += 1

I'm sure there's a better way to do this, I just want to understand why this particular method isn't working. Thank you in advance!

Python output is buffered by default. See e.g. this article, or this one, or this question. You need to either disabling buffering or explicitly flush after each write (print("-", end="", flush=True)).
